# UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw :app_exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am having trouble by running my app locally , it worked normally before and still working on server, but recently I am not able to run it locally:

I am using

> bundle exec rails -v Rails 5.2.4.1
>
> bundle exec ruby  -v ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260)
>   [x86_64-darwin19]
>
> bundle exec rails s

whatever page I tried to open on my rails app locally I got following error

> > UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw :app_exception   from
> >     /.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:137:in
> >     `throw'
>
> I try to trace error :
>
> .rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb
>   133:       end    134:    135:       def call_app(env)    136:
>   @app.call(env)    137:       rescue => e    138:         byebug
>   => 139:         throw :app_exception, e    140:       end    141:   end    142: end (byebug) e

it looks that is is triggered in

> (byebug) view.send(method_name, locals, buffer, &block)
>   *** FrozenError Exception: can't modify frozen fatal
>
> from
>   .rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb

it looks to me like ruby error and don't have any idea how to solve it . Can someone help me with this ? 
I tried also to use following ruby versions 2.6.1, 2.6.3, 2.6.5 but error is same there.

Comment: I resolved the issue. gem 'wicked_pdf' cause this issue

Comment: How did you solve the issue, Did you remove 'wicked_pdf' gem. What is solution if i want to use the gem 'wicked_pdf'

@Ivan Blazevic

Answer (score 5):

[wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) with version **2.0.2** along with Rails 5.2.4.2 causes the issue.

If you use **1.4.0** version, this is working fine